# How to solve libboost_system.so.1.58.0 error?

Tags: xubuntu

I upgraded my Ubuntu 16 to Ubuntu 18 two days ago, and now I'm trying to run something (which was running smoothly on Ubuntu 16) but the following error raised

```
error while loading shared libraries: libboost_iostreams.so.1.58.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How to solve this?
Note: I'm completely new to Linux.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to run? Ubuntu 18 has newer versions of this library, so maybe the app you're running didn't get upgraded.

Comment: I'm trying to run P4 code

Comment: Was it something you compiled yourself? If so, you probably have to rebuild it so that it links to the new libraries.

Comment: It's not my code. I'm just trying to make some tests.
So the problem can not be solved?

Comment: You should contact the developer. It could be as simple as recompiling the source or  installing the xenial binary (not sure that's even possible; never tried it).

Comment: thank you for the suggestion.